# Solving $x^{x^6}=\sqrt{2}$ analytically

Tags: analysis, exponential-function

I've been trying to solve the equation:

$$x^{x^6}=\sqrt{2}$$

by Newton's method, I got the answer to be somewhere around 1.1562. I was wondering if there was a way to solve it analytically, you know getting an exact answer. I've been trying for a couple of hours now, but any exact solution eludes me.

Comment: Please include your work, an explanation of what you did to get an answer somewhere around 1.1562.

Comment: Hi @amWhy, 
I just found the derivative and applied the Newton Raphson method to find the root. I didn't think any explanation was needed.

Comment: Providing such context is helpful to potential answerers, to help us better understand what you've tried, what you know, etc., so we can answer appropriately.

Comment: I don't put it as an answer but put $y=x^6$ and use Lambert's function

Comment: I don't think the answer will be different from your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3678091/solving-xx6-2-analytically).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving $x^{x^6} = 2$ analytically](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3678091/solving-xx6-2-analytically)

Comment: @amWhy it's my own question. I forgot to put the sqrt in that one

Comment: In future please edit your question rather than ask a brand new one. It keeps the site from being cluttered with unnecessarily many similar questions.

Comment: @VipulRajan it's not a nice policy to post a question multiple times, especially after just half an hour. As per your question, you're probably not going to find an analytic expression in terms of elementary functions. You can see if you can compute the coefficients in Newton's method analytically.

Comment: I apologise for that. I'd keep that in mind here on out and won't post twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments, there is an analytical solution in terms of Lambert function
$$x^{x^a}=b \implies x=\sqrt[a] {\frac{a \log (b)}{W(a \log (b))}}$$